# Creating a summary report for multiple layers intersecting a buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, reports, closest-facility

I tried to use the Closest Facility tool in Network Analyst to find locations that were within a 10 minute walk to a number of my offices, however that job failed after 4 hours with a generic error.  I'm thinking the incidents table was way too big since there were about 400K locations in that combined table.

My workaround was to instead create a service area for each of my offices with 5 and 10 minute walk-time buffers.  I then used **Select by Location** on each of the other layers with (for lack of a better term) "partner sites" to find those sites that were within the walkable service area.  That actually worked really well and was super fast (less than a minute for each layer.)

[image: ArcGIS Pro Screenshot]

So now I have my offices, the service area buffers, and points from (up to) five different layers.  I'd like to also include a PDF report that includes the table data from those layers.  Using the office in the screenshot above, I'd like there to be a page for "Office 755" that has a table with all of the office/business names, address, contact info, etc. for each of the points from those 5 different layers.

I've tried merging the other five layers, but the tool won't allow the buffer polygon to be combined with the other layers (error is "The shape type `*PATH*` is not the same as previously entered datasets") so it just combines all the points into one layer, but doesn't associate those points in any way with the the nearby office buffer they're contained in.

I can created a canned report that aggregates all of those points by city or county (once they're all combined in one layer, but I have a few offices in the same city or county, so that one doesn't really do the trick either.

Is there another way to consolidate this info into one report/view for each of my offices?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [Spatial Map Series](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/spatial-map-series.htm) will do most of the things you are expecting. Specifically it will allow you to set up a layout with a selected feature as a map extent, query related features, and update a table within the layout to show only selected, related records. It will also allow for cycling through all the sites and exporting each of them as a PDF.

You will have to do all the to setup of the map series (because it can't read minds yet) then check the PDFs before combining them into a single report.